# Open JDK Font issue in Linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts, jasper-reports, openjdk-11

Running a Java application which uses Jasper to generate the report on Open JDK 11.0.3-64 version. Application works fine on the windows where as it fails to generate the report in Linux. Appears like the JDK on linux is missing the ***fontconfig.properties.src*** & ***fontconfig.bfc*** file.  As a result JDK is not able to find the fonts needed to generate the report. Application throws the below error

***INFO: Looking for binary fontconfig file : /tomcat/spring/java/jdk1.11.0.3-64/lib/fontconfig.bfc***

***Feb 23, 2021 12:46:07 PM sun.awt.FontConfiguration findFontConfigFile
INFO: Did not find a fontconfig file.***

Anyone faced a similar issue ?

Comment: What version of JasperReports library are you using?

Comment: Did you check this [issue](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/70) and this [one](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/2659)? You can find some workaround there

Comment: Adding the fontconfig package on the Linux server helped fix the issue.